# API resolved without sending a response for /api/xyz. How do I resolve this error in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am currently working on an e-commerce site in React/NextJS, and am having trouble working out why my api endpoints are not sending a response. The same problem exists for both the addProduct and updateProduct endpoints.  The products are added/updated just fine but I have this error and I am not getting any other useful error messages, likely because I am not using try/catch statements properly, but I am unsure!

addproduct.js 'api/addproduct'

```
import {connectToDatabase} from '../../lib/mongodb'

async function addProduct(item){

    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    const resp = await db
        .collection("stock")
        .insertOne(item)   
    return resp
}

const post = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var colourList=[]
        var sizeList=[]

        Object.keys(req.body).forEach( key => {
            
            if (key.substring(0,7) == "colour-"){
                colourList.push(req.body[key])
            }
            if (key.substring(0,9) == "checkbox-"){
                sizeList.push(key.substring(9))
            }
        
        })
        // Extract Form Data
        var newItem =  {
            id : req.body["id"],
            name : req.body["name"],
            description : req.body["description"],
            gender : req.body["gender"],
            price : req.body["price"],
            isOnSale : req.body["isOnSale"],
            discount : req.body["discount"],
            colours : colourList,
            sizes : sizeList,

        }
        // debug
        console.log(req.body)
    
        // add the stock to the db
        const resp = await addProduct(newItem)

        res.status(201).send({ message: "Item Added", response: resp })
        return
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(err).json({});
      }
};


export default (req, res) => {
    req.method === "POST"
      ? post(req, res)
      : req.method === "PUT"
      ? console.log("PUT")
      : req.method === "DELETE"
      ? console.log("DELETE")
      : req.method === "GET"
      ? console.log("GET")
      : res.status(404).send("");
  };
```

updateproduct.js 'api/updateproduct'

```
import {connectToDatabase} from '../../lib/mongodb'


async function updateProduct(updatedItem){

    var query = { id: updatedItem.id };
    var newValues = 
        { $set: { 
                id: updatedItem.id,
                name: updatedItem.name,
                description: updatedItem.description,
                gender: updatedItem.gender,
                price: updatedItem.price,
                isOnSale: updatedItem.isOnSale,
                discount: updatedItem.discount,
                colours: updatedItem.colours,
                sizes: updatedItem.sizes
            } 
        };
    // debug
    console.log("newValues:")
    console.log(newValues)
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    const resp = await db
        .collection("stock")
        .updateOne(query, newValues, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 document updated");
          });  
    return resp
}

const post = async (req, res) => {

   
    var colourList=[]
    var sizeList=[]

    Object.keys(req.body).forEach( key => {
        
        if (key.substring(0,7) == "colour-"){
            colourList.push(req.body[key])
        }
        if (key.substring(0,9) == "checkbox-"){
            sizeList.push(key.substring(9))
        }
    })
    // Extract Form Data
    var updatedItem =  {
        id : req.body['id'],
        name : req.body['name'],
        description : req.body['description'],
        gender : req.body['gender'],
        price : req.body['price'],
        isOnSale : req.body['isOnSale'],
        discount : req.body['discount'],
        colours : colourList,
        sizes : sizeList,

    }
    // debug
    console.log("Body:")
    console.log(req.body)
    
 
    // update the stock in  db
    const resp = await updateProduct(updatedItem)
    res.status(201).send({ message: 'Item Updated' })
    return


};


export default (req, res) => {
    req.method === "POST"
      ? post(req, res)
      : req.method === "PUT"
      ? console.log("PUT")
      : req.method === "DELETE"
      ? console.log("DELETE")
      : req.method === "GET"
      ? console.log("GET")
      : res.status(404).send("");
  };
```

AddProductForm.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import  { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function AddProductForm({ }) {
     
    const router = useRouter()
    // userInput is for adding colours.
    const [userInput, setUserInput ] = useState('');

    // Form State Variables
    const [id, setId] = useState('')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
    const [gender, setGender] = useState('')
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('')
    const [isOnSale, setIsOnSale] = useState('')
    const [discount, setDiscount] = useState('')
    const [colours, setColours ] = useState([]);

    var sizesList = {
        "checkbox-xs":false,
        "checkbox-s":false,
        "checkbox-m":false,
        "checkbox-l":false,
        "checkbox-xl":false,
        "checkbox-xxl":false}     
    
    const [sizes, setSizes] = useState(sizesList)
  
    
    const handleAddProduct = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();  
        var body = {id: id,
                    name: name,
                    description: description,
                    gender: gender,
                    price: price,
                    isOnSale: isOnSale,
                    discount: discount}

        colours.forEach( (colour, index) => {
                        body[`colour-${index}`]=  colour.colour})

        Object.keys(sizes).forEach( (key, index) => { 
                        if(sizes[key] == true) {
                            body[key] = true
                        }
                    })
         const options = {
            body: JSON.stringify(body),     
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
        }

    
      const response = await fetch(
            "/api/addproduct", options
            
      )
      var message = await response.json();
      alert(message['message'])
      router.push("/admin/inventory")
      //document.getElementById("add-item-form").reset();
        // .then(response => {
        //   alert(response['message'])
        //   router.push("/admin/inventory")
        // })
        // .catch(error => {
        //   console.log(error)
        // })
    }
    
    const handleChangeColour = (e) => {
        setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value)
      }
      
    const handleRemoveColour = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const colourId = e.target.getAttribute("name")
        setColours(colours.filter(colour => colour.id != colourId));   
    }
    
    const addColour = (userInput) => {
        let copy = [...colours];
        
        setColours(copy);
        copy.push({id: colours.length + 1, colour: userInput});
    }

    const handleAddColour = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addColour(userInput);
        setUserInput("");
    }
     const handleChangeSizes = (e) => {
         sizesList = sizes
         sizesList[e.target.name] = e.target.checked
         setSizes(sizesList)
     }

    return (

            <Form id="add-item-form"  onSubmit={handleAddProduct}>
              <div className="row">
                <div className ="col-lg-6">
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formProductId">
                    <Form.Control type="text" name="formProductId" placeholder="Enter Product Id" onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)} required/>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formProductName">
                    <Form.Control name="formProductName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Name" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}required/>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formProductGender">
                  <Form.Select name="formProductGender" aria-label="Gender Select" onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)} required>
                    <option>Is this male, female, or both</option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    <option value="Unisex">Unisex</option>
                  </Form.Select>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formProductPrice" >
                    <Form.Control name="formProductPrice" type="number" placeholder="Enter Product Price" onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)} required/>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formProductDiscount">
                    <Form.Control name="formProductDiscount" type="number" placeholder="Enter Current Discount (in %)" onChange={e => setDiscount(e.target.value)} required/>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formProductIsOnSale">
                    <Form.Select name="formProductIsOnSale" aria-label="Sale Select" onChange={e => setIsOnSale(e.target.value)} required>
                      <option>Is this product on sale?</option>
                      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                      <option value="No">No</option>
                    </Form.Select>
                  </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div className ="col-lg-6">
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3 " controlId="formProductDescription">
                    <Form.Control name="formProductDescription" type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Description" onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} required/>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3 " controlId="formProductSizes">
                    <Form.Label>Available Sizes</Form.Label>
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
                      <div className="col-sm-8">
                        <div className="row">
                          {['xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl'].map(function(size, index){
                            return   (                      
                              <div className="col" key={index}>
                                <Form.Check 
                                  type='checkbox'
                                  id={`checkbox-${size}`}
                                  name={`checkbox-${size}`}
                                  label={`${size}`}
                                  onChange={handleChangeSizes}
                                />
                              </div>
                            )})}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
                    </div>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formProductColours">
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col">
                        <Form.Label className="ml-5">Available Colours</Form.Label>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col">
                        <input value={userInput} type="text" onChange={handleChangeColour} placeholder="Enter Colour..."/>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col pb-1">
                        <div className="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm mb-1" onClick={handleAddColour}>+</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {colours.map(colour => {
                      return (
                        <>
                        <div className="row" key={colour.id}>
                          <div className="col">
                            <div > {colour.colour} </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="col">
                          <div className="col pb-1">
                            <div name={colour.id} class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm mb-1" onClick={handleRemoveColour}>-</div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name={`colour-{colour.colour}`}></input>
                        </>
                      )
                    })}
                  </Form.Group>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-success">
                Add Product
              </button>
            </Form>

    )
}
```

I'd like help working out why the api isn't sending a response or error, and also how do I effectively deal with errors using try/catch. Am I right just to wrap all the code inside the function in a try/catch block?

any assistance always appreciated.

UPDATED I have added the AddProductForm.js to show how I am calling the api route.

Comment: Try adding an `await` before your `post()` call, i.e. `await post(req, res)`. I'd also recommend you replace that long ternary operator with an `if`/`else` or `switch` statement for readability.

Comment: I have just updated the question to include the code from the AddProductForm.js file. I used 'await fetch'

Comment: You still need to await the `post` call though.

Comment: If i put await in front of post it just shows a syntax error could you please show an example